# Creating Density Map using Hexagonal Grids in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, mapping, density, hexagonal-grid

I have residential density (number of dwellings/area) data for several areas. I want to create a density map using hexagonal grids. I have extracted the hexagonal grids according to the area extent using the *mmqgis* plugin and *Select by Location* tool. Now I am stuck with combining the density data to the hexagon layer.

Screenshot of My data:

[image]

The hexagonal grids that I have created:

[image: Hexagon]

Now I want to plot the Residential Density Data to on the hexagonal grid map.

One possible way can be to create a dot density map from the density layer and manually replace the dots in a point feature and use the *Count Points in Polygon* tool. But this will be very inefficient. Is there any better way?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? As the question is written, I don't understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @Babel, I have added screenshots. Hope these are helpful.

Comment: How does your density data look like? Is it points or polygons? FYI you can create a grid in QGIS with "Create Grid", MMQGIS is not needed for that anymore.

Comment: Still not sure how you want to connect the density data to the grid. The attribute table you added contains no. of residents and area, so probably it's a polygon layer? The grid cells are much smaller then the polygons? So several neighboring cells will get the same value? Can you share your data - or at least a sample of it - even dummy data?

Comment: The attribute table has the density values already calculated (last column) and yes, it is a polygon layer.

Comment: I want to show the Residential density data of the the table as hexagonal grids. When I create the grids, the density data does not get included to the layer. That's what I am trying to do; include the density data to the grid and symbolize using graduated color. My concepts may be wrong about hexagonal grids since I am trying this for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was really an easy solution. I had to do spatial join with the hexagon grid layer and polygon layer (which had the residential density data). The tool *join attributes by location* is used.

Comment: I apologize for not being able to clarify my problem. I think I forgot to mention that my hexagon grid layer and polygon layer (having residential data) were different.